# Rounding numbers in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, numbers, list-comprehension

I am trying to round all the numbers to two decimal places in a list of lists as below:

```
a = [[4.5555, 5.6666, 8.3365], [10.4345, 1.574355. 0.7216313]]
b = [x for x in a for y in [round(z, 2) for z in x]]
```

I am trying to use a list comprehension to do this, but cannot get it going. The b variable just returns the same thing as a. Is this the best way to go about it? Is there a better alternative way? Thanks!

Comment: Please do show us your list comprehension attempt.

Comment: Don't try to round numbers as you always have some floating point errors. Instead just round them when you print them out. Whenever doing calculations you should do so with the maximum number of digits you have.

Comment: Consider numpy: `np.round()` will work on multi-dimensional data no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to *nest* your list comprehensions:

```
[[np.round(float(i), 2) for i in nested] for nested in outerlist]
```

The outer list comprehension loops over your outer list object, then applies an inner list comprehension for each sublist. This nested comprehension is something you apply to produce a new sublist, so you put it on the left-hand side.

Comment: Ok so I was just reversing the nested list comprehension...works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your tags suggset that `a` is actually a Numpy array and not a nested Python list.  In that case, you can use the `round()` method on the array object to get a rounded copy of the array:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.randn(3, 3)
>>> a
array([[ 1.46998835,  0.62139675,  0.37665545],
       [-0.79925019, -0.51251798,  1.36500036],
       [ 0.66339687, -1.22586919,  1.68054346]])
>>> a.round(3)
array([[ 1.47 ,  0.621,  0.377],
       [-0.799, -0.513,  1.365],
       [ 0.663, -1.226,  1.681]])
```

You can round the array in place, without creating a copy, using `a.round(3, out=a)`.

Comment: removed the numpy tag

Comment: @KidSudi: If you want to perform operations like this one, you _should_ use Numpy, because it will be significantly easier. (And your code example still uses `np.round()`.)

Comment: Well my data was actually gathered from a data frame. I wanted to plot the table of the data frame using matplotlib, but from what I gathered you cannot create a table figure as such. Thus, I exported the data from the data frame into a list of lists (i.e. each list is a row in the data frame). Then I just plotted the table within a plot figure. Not sure if there is a better way to go about this...

Comment: I'm guessing that by "data frame" you mean a pandas `DataFrame` object.  If so, simply use the [`plot()` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) on the object itself.  It uses Matplotlib to plot the data.

Comment: @KidSudi: Reading your comment again, are you actually trying to typeset a table?  A plot is a graphical visualisation of the data, and a table is generally not considered a plot.  In any case, converting the pandas `DataFrame` object to a Python list is unnecesaarily complex and slow.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. In R you can do this very easily, but I'm having trouble doing this through Python...Is there a correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call np.round on your list of lists, no need for a comprehension

```
import numpy as np
a = ([[4.5555, 5.6666, 8.3365], [10.4345, 1.574355, 0.7216313]])
print np.round(a,2)
[[  4.56   5.67   8.34]
 [ 10.43   1.57   0.72]]
```